# Is there a style guide for German similar to The Elements of Style for English?

Tags: resource, style, book

Is there a German style guide similar to "[The Elements of Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020530902X)" by Strunk and White or "[Style: The Basics of Clarity and Grace](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321112520)" which are well known for English?

Answer (score 3):

One style guide I can absolutely recommend is [*Deutsch für Kenner*](http://www.amazon.de/Deutsch-f%C3%BCr-Kenner-neue-Stilkunde/dp/3492244610) by [Wolf Schneider](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_Schneider), a German journalist and language critic. The book is both witty and clearly structured. (Note that it takes a firm stand and is by no means a neutral guide; some even call it arrogant.) Important to know: You'll need a good knowledge of German to really enjoy the book.

<sup>If you've already read *Deutsch für Profis* or *Deutsch fürs Leben*, then you already saw a lot of the contents of *Deutsch für Kenner*.</sup>

Comment: The answer is much appreciated. The reason I have not accepted so far is that based on the reviews this book is a very opinionated, very critical review of actual German language misuse. This could be alright but it seems a bit wearisome. I'll give it a bit more time and then accept your answer.

Comment: Oh, it's not wearisome. At some points I find it slightly repetetive (but this gets bad only if you _also_ read _Deutsch für Profis_), but it's really fun to read. I learned of the book from someone sitting next to me in a local train who was laughing from time to time. There are lots of (opinionated) great and funny examples from which you can learn a lot.