# Is there a German style guide similar to The Chicago Manual of Style?

Tags: style

I am looking for a style guide similar to [The Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html).

Comment: Without reading the style guide, what are it's unique or selling points? What are you looking for in your own words?

Comment: This https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3770/43989 may answer your question.

Comment: @planetmaker - The CMS is well known in the English speaking world, but I guess if your native language is German you may not have heard of it. It's kind of the de factor standard for the format of research papers and other scholarly work, particularly when it comes to citation formatting.

Comment: @RDBury: "It's kind of the de factor standard for the format of research papers and other scholarly work, particularly when it comes to citation formatting." - umm ... I agree the CMS is well known in the English speaking world, but *particularly* when it comes to citation formatting, each publisher tends to follow their own standard: https://pitt.libguides.com/citationhelp/overview

Comment: Also, there is a lot of competition: there's the Associated Press Stylebook, and there's APA style and MLA style for academics, and probably a dozen or so lesser known ones. In German, *Duden*, while no longer a de-facto monopoly, still has some clout. *Gutes und richtiges Deutsch* comes to mind.